# How would you design BPM application in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database-design, entity-attribute-value

we have created a simple asp.net/sqlserver 2000 based Business Process Management tool in which we have a feature that user can create simple one column form and attached to the process and define rules and path.

We save the dynamically created forms controls values in EAV design tables but as the transactions is increasing we are have the performance issue on reporting on that custom forms values , my question is whats the alternative to this problem in which main requirement of the BPM solution is that user will create forms dynamically ,and what do u guys think the implementation of other big vendors of BPM  like Skelta/ultimus/K2.net are managing this requirement. **Do u thing xml can save me ?? if yes then how or How u guys will design the model of BPM applications**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of EAV.  It's using a relational database to solve a problem relational databases are not designed to solve.

I'd recommend you design a [Domain-Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) to represent your forms definitions.  You can use XML as a format.

Or else you should use [RDF](http://www.openrdf.org) for dynamically-structured data.